# How to set an Int16 value to a Nullable<Enum> property using reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-2.0

I need to do this:-

**MyClass.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace set_property__Enum_To_Nullable_Enum
{
    public enum MyEnum : short
    {
        One, 
        Two, 
        Three 
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
        public string MyStringProperty { get; set; }
        public MyEnum? MyEnumProperty { get; set; }

        public void ShowAll(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);            
            Console.WriteLine("String   = " + MyStringProperty);
            Console.WriteLine("Enum   = " + MyEnumProperty.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace set_property__Enum_To_Nullable_Enum
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Names
            string myAssemblyName = "MyAssembly";
            string myNamespaceName = "set_property__Enum_To_Nullable_Enum";
            string myClassName = "MyClass";
            string propertyNameOne = "MyStringProperty";
            string propertyNameTwo = "MyEnumProperty";

            //Data            
            string myString = "Hello World!";
            short myInteger = 1;

            //Preprocessing
            Assembly myAssmbly = Assembly.Load(myAssemblyName);
            Type myType = myAssmbly.GetType(myNamespaceName + "." + myClassName);

            //Create class-instance
            object objectInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);

            //Set property-values
            PropertyInfo propertyInfoOne = myType.GetProperty(propertyNameOne);
            propertyInfoOne.SetValue(objectInstance, myString, null);

            PropertyInfo propertyInfoTwo = myType.GetProperty(propertyNameTwo);
            propertyInfoTwo.SetValue(objectInstance, myInteger, null);//<---------------

            //Call method
            myType.InvokeMember("ShowAll",
                                        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
                                        null,
                                        objectInstance,
                                        new object[] { "My name is Khan" });

            string end = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

But Int32 value is not automatically converted to MyEnum.

At the specific line, an exception is being generated.

```
Object of type 'System.Int16' cannot be converted to type 'System.Nullable`1[set_property__Enum_To_Nullable_Enum.MyEnum]'.
```

How to do it?

## Edit

I need further help please!

Enum.ToObject() can not handle null.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK, you need to use `Enum.ToObject` in this case, since you're using reflection. But you also need to unwrap the nullable to use that, which `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` does for you.

So, you need to get the `Type` corresponding to `MyEnum`:

```
Type nullableEnumType = propertyInfoTwo.PropertyType;
Type enumType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(nullableEnumType);
```

then use `Enum.ToObject` to produce a boxed instance of `MyEnum` with the value you specify:

```
object enumValue = Enum.ToObject(enumType, myInteger);
```

So, putting it all together:

```
object enumValue = Enum.ToObject(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfoTwo.PropertyType), myInteger);
propertyInfoTwo.SetValue(objectInstance, enumValue, null);
```

**EDIT:**

if `myInteger` is nullable, itself, you should use:

```
object enumValue = 
    myInteger.HasValue
        ? Enum.ToObject(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyInfoTwo.PropertyType), myInteger.Value);
        : null;
```

Comment: That was not my problem. Enum.ToObject()  can't handle  null. So whenever myInteger==null, the function-call fails. How to solve that?

Comment: @Saqib: that does solve your problem. If `myInteger` is not null (`myInteger.HasValue`) it calls `Enum.ToObject` on the value of `myInteger`, else it assigns null to `enumValue`.

Comment: Your answer allowed me to test for : `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(nullableEnumType).IsEnum` ~ thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it?

```
propertyInfoTwo.SetValue(objectInstance, (MyEnum?)myInteger, null);
```

Comment: This solution works for the code you posted. If this is not the solution you need, please post the relevant code. I don't have a crystal ball I'm afraid.

Comment: It must work in case of any Enum type, not only MyEnum. Anyway, I found my solution.

Answer (score 0):

use int instead of short or

```
enum MyEnum : Int16
```

or convert the short to an int.

**update:**
try

```
short? MyInteger = 1;
```

Comment: The updated solution can not be used. Coz, this short value will come from a database table.