# c# convert from System.Reflection.FieldInfo to user defined type

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I have the following classes Point and Class2. My purpose is to retrieve in Class2 all Points´ instances to store them in a List.

```
public class Point
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        string col;

        public Point(int abs, int ord, string clr)
        {
            this.x = abs;
            this.y = ord;
            this.col = clr;
        }

        public string toColor()
        {
            return this.col;
        }

        public int Addition()
        {
            return (this.x + this.y);
        }
    }

class Class2
    {
        int test;
        Point pt1;
        Point pt2;
        Point pt3;
        List<Point> listPt = new List<Point>() { };

        public Class2()
        {
            test = 100;
            this.pt1 = new Point(2, 3, "red");
            this.pt2 = new Point(1, 30, "blue");
            this.pt3 = new Point(5, 10, "black");
        }

        public List<Point> getAllPoint() 
        {
            foreach (var field in this.GetType().GetFields())
            {
                //retrieve current type of the anonimous type variable
                Type fieldType = field.FieldType;

                if (fieldType == typeof(Point))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("POINT: {0}", field.ToString());
                    //listPt.Add(field); //error
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Field {0} is not a Point", field.ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
            return listPt;
        }
    }
```

But it does not work because field is of type "System.Reflection.FieldInfo", how can I do that working? 
I read a lot of articles but I did not find the solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

[Type conversion issue when setting property through reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270183/type-conversion-issue-when-setting-property-through-reflection)

http://technico.qnownow.com/how-to-set-property-value-using-reflection-in-c/

[Convert variable to type only known at run-time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010144/convert-variable-to-type-only-known-at-run-time)

...

(I want to do that: at the end a class will have Point instances depending on a db, so I cannot know how much Point I will have, and I will need to launch a member function like Addition.)

Thank for all ideas!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`FieldInfo.GetValue()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx) method:

```
listPt.Add((Point)field.GetValue(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the [GetFields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch9714z3.aspx) call you are using. By default, GetFields returns all public instance fields, and your points are declared as **private** instance fields. You need to use the [other overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ztex2dc.aspx), that allows for much more fine-grained control of the fields you are getting as a result

If I change that line to:

```
this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)
```

I get the following result:

```
Field Int32 test is not a Point
POINT: Point pt1
POINT: Point pt2
POINT: Point pt3
Field System.Collections.Generic.List`1[UserQuery+Point] listPt is not a Point
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will work, but off the top of my head:

```
public List<Point> getAllPoint() 
        {
            return (from field in this.GetType().GetFields() where field.FieldType == typeof(Point) select (Point)field.GetValue(this)).ToList();
        }
```