# Assigning to an array field through reflection in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, reflection

I use reflection to get FieldInfos in a class and assign to them with FieldInfo.SetValue. It works fine when i assign primitive types (i use Convert.ChangeType to convert from object to type) but doesn't work if the field is an array. It works if i use Array.Cast but the type is only known at runtime so i cant cast.
I saw lots of topics on this but none of them worked so far.

I get this exception:

> ArgumentException: Object type System.Object[] cannot be converted to target type: System.Single[]

I know why it happens i just can't find a way to convert the data. Any ideas?

EDIT: relevant code:

```
 public static object Deserialize (string path){
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        ConstructorInfo ci = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        object newObj = ci.Invoke(new object[] {});
        Type type = Type.GetType(lines[0], true);
        FieldInfo[] fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public);



        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++){
            FieldInfo thisField = currentType.GetField(lines[i]);
                if (thisField != null) {
                    if (line != "") {
                        if (fieldType == typeof(string)) {
                            thisField.SetValue(currentObject, line);
                            thisField = null;
                        }
                        else if (fieldType.IsPrimitive) {
                            val = Convert.ChangeType(line, fieldType);
                            thisField.SetValue(currentObject, val);
                            thisField = null;
                        }
                        else if (fieldType.IsArray){
                            string[] values = ReadUntil(']');
                            //ReadUntil just returns the values as string[] as read from text file
                            object[] newValues = Convert.ChangeType(values, fieldType);

                            thisField.SetValue(newObj, newValues);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    }
```

Comment: It would help if you could please show the relevant code.

Comment: checkout this possible duplicate posting - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270183/type-conversion-issue-when-setting-property-through-reflection

Comment: thanks but as i've said: i can assign primitives just fine - the only problem is with arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
else if (fieldType.IsArray)
{
    string[] values = ReadUntil(']');
    var elementType = fieldType.GetElementType();
    if (elementType == typeof(string))
        thisField.SetValue(newObj, values);
    else
    {
        var actualValues = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, values.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
            actualValues.SetValue(Convert.ChangeType(values[i], elementType), i);
        thisField.SetValue(newObj, actualValues);
    }
}
```

[Type.GetElementType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype(v=vs.110).aspx) method is used to retrieve the type of the array elements, then [Array.CreateInstance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.createinstance(v=vs.110).aspx) method to create an array of the desired type, and finally [Array.SetValue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) method to populate the new array elements with the converted values.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what i was looking for :)